# What's the word to describe the sound of a pebble (or pebbles) falling on a rock surface? Clack, tap, clank

Tags: single-word-requests, sounds

What's the word that could best describe the sound of a pebble (or pebbles) falling on a rock surface? Clack, tap, clank...? Thanks!

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=the+pebbles+made+a+*+sound

Comment: *The pebbles [**clattered**.](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22pebbles+clattered%22)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[A continuous rattling of hard objects striking each other is often described onomatopoeically as "clattering"](http://www.onomatopoeialist.com/clatter/). The term is well suited for either multiple pebbles or multiple contacts of one pebble with a rock. A single controlled strike of a single pebble would probably be better described as a "[click](http://www.onomatopoeialist.com/clicking/)" (for a higher, sharper noise, if the pebble and rock are both smooth, for example) or a clack or tap, as you wrote. "[Clank](http://www.onomatopoeialist.com/clank/)" generally implies metal rather than stone.